# React - useEffect with setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I have a Functional Component with `setInterval` inside `useEffect`.
But value inside `loadData` is always equal to initial one (0), despite the correct render.

How I can get the current `value` inside `loadData` that calling by `setInterval`?

```
    ...
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    const [service, setService] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setService(new ApiService());
    }, [])

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const timerId = setInterval(loadData, 1000 * 5);
            return () => clearInterval(timerId);
        }, 
        [service]
    )

    async function loadData() {
        const result = await service.getData();
        console.log("old value: ", value); // "value" is always 0 (initial)
        setValue(result.data.value);
    } 

    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code depends on the `value` constant to update it. Intuitively this makes sense, but the problem has to do with closures. `setValue` and `value` are defined during the render cycle of the component. In other words, their definition is fixed.

The set function (`setValue`) of `useState()` passes the current/old value as a parameter. You should use this *functional updates* approach in `useState()`:

```js
setValue((prevState) => {
  console.log("old value: ", prevState);
  return result.data.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1:

React's answer to this is to use the currently experimental hook, [`useEffectEvent()`](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-effect-event):

```js
const loadData useEffectEvent(async function() { // wrap your callback that needs to see the 'latest' value in the `useEffectEvent` hook call
  const result = await service.getData();
  console.log("old value: ", value); // `value` should now be the latest value 
  setValue(result.data.value);
});
```

The `useEffectEvent()` allows you to create a callback function that "sees" the latest reactive values (ie: state, props) in your component (without needing to specify the hook as a dependency). This hook is currently experimental, so you need to import it like so (as it's experimental, the behavior may change or break in the future):

```
import { experimental_useEffectEvent as useEffectEvent } from 'react';
```

alternatively, a safer alternative is to create your own version of the hook that behaves in a *similar* (not exactly the same) way. The main idea of this hook is that it replicates the behavior of allowing you to see the reactive values (note: you may want to call this custom version something other than `useEffectEvent()` as it's not a one-for-one replacement):

```
// Rough example of how `useEffectEvent` could be implemented.
// Source: https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#internal-implementation
import { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useCallback } from "react";
export function useEffectEvent(handler) { // Suggestion: Rename this hook to something else
  const handlerRef = useRef(null);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    handlerRef.current = handler;
  });
  return useCallback((...args) => {
    const fn = handlerRef.current;
    return fn(...args);
  }, []);
}
```

---

#### Option 2:

The below solution is another option, which may be ok for your use case. The thing to keep in mind about the below option is that it will cause your timer to pause when your dependent `value` changes. The main issue with your code currently is that your `useEffect()` doesn't declare the function `loadData` as a dependency. When you don't declare your function as a dependency, then the timer will call ann old version of your function and so you'll end up with stale-state due to `loadData` closing over an older version of the `value` state:

```js
const loadData = useCallback(async function() {
  const result = await service.getData();
  console.log("old value: ", value); // "value" is always 0 (initial)
  setValue(result.data.value);
}, [service, value]);


useEffect(() => {
  const timerId = setInterval(loadData, 1000 * 5);
  return () => clearInterval(timerId);
}, [loadData]);
```

The above wraps your function in the hook `useCallback()`, which returns the same function reference if the dependency array: `service` or `data` contains the same values as that of the previous render. If the values in the dependency array change, then the function assigned to `loadData` will be a new function reference. Using `loadData` as a dependency to your `useEffect()` hook allows you to re-define the interval to refer to the newly created `loadData` callback when either `service` or `value` changes. Runnable example below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  const {useState, useEffect, useCallback} = React;

  const getRandomAsync = () => new Promise((resolve) => { // simulate api call
    setTimeout(resolve, 10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  });

  const App = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    const loadData = useCallback(async () => {
      const num = await getRandomAsync();
      console.log("Got random number:", num);
      console.log("Value currently is:", value);
      setValue(num);
    }, [value]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const timerId = setInterval(loadData, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(timerId);
    }, [loadData]);

    return <p>{value}</p>;
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't the "setInterval" now called every time the service or value changes? I'd prefer to trigger the interval only if the component mounts, that way you can prevent any memory leaks as well.

Comment: Yes, but `service` was already a dependency to the useEffect hook in OPs question, so that behavior is the same. The cleanup function with clearInterval() should handle cleaning up the old running interval, which will allow the new interval with a reference to the new `loadData` function to execute. Depending on what OP is trying to do, using prevState within the setter like you have shown might be a better option