why doesn't currentRaceIndex get its new value before being used in handleRaceData
My problem is that currentRaceIndex has the initial value i assigned it as in const [currentRaceIndex, setCurrentRaceIndex] = useState(-1); but i need it to be updated to its correct value from handleRaceQueue before being used in handleRaceData function. Does the problem come from react's asynchronous nature, where setCurrentRaceIndex takes time to set the value and isn't set yet when handleRaceData checks it in its if statement? How do i fix this?
useEffect(() => {
        // Request the latest race data and queue position from the server
        socket.emit("getRaceData");
        socket.emit("getQueuePosition");

        const handleRaceQueue = (queue) => {
            console.log("Queue pos from server: " + queue)
            setCurrentRaceIndex(queue); 
        };

        const handleRaceData = (data) => {
            
            if (areAllRacesFinished === true && data.length > currentRaceIndex+1) {
                console.log("data.length:", data.length);
                console.log("currentRaceIndex+1:", currentRaceIndex+1);
                setAreAllRacesFinished(false);
                socket.emit("updateAreAllRacesFinished", false);
            }

            setRaceData(data);
        };

        const handleAreAllRacesFinished = (data) => {
            console.log("AreAllRacesFinished value from server: " + data);
            setAreAllRacesFinished(data); 
        };

        const handleTimerUpdate = (data) => {
            if (data.raceName === currentRace?.raceName) {
                setTimeRemaining(data.timeRemaining);
            }
        };

        socket.on("queuePosition", handleRaceQueue);
        socket.on("raceData", handleRaceData);
        socket.on("timerUpdate", handleTimerUpdate);
        socket.on("areAllRacesFinished", handleAreAllRacesFinished);

        return () => {
            socket.off("queuePosition", handleRaceQueue);
            socket.off("raceData", handleRaceData);
            socket.off("timerUpdate", handleTimerUpdate);
            socket.off("areAllRacesFinished", handleAreAllRacesFinished);
        };
    }, [currentRace?.raceName]); 


This isn't so much an asynchronous state issue but rather it's a closure issue leading to stale state. Notice how you're using state values in your useEffect callback without declaring them as dependencies? This will cause your effect callback to continue to refer to old state values as your component rerenders with new ones. Either update your dependencies, or use something like an effect-event.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68542491/5648954

It may also be worth considering if you need these things to be state - does your UI (ie: the JSX you're returning) refer to these things (such as currentRaceIndex ?). If not, then potentially you can use a ref which won't fall into the same closure issues states face.

Thank you, i got it fixed, then i got a new problem, where areAllRacesFinished wasnt updating properly when switching pages in the navigator but i fixed that aswell by adding a socket.emit("getAreAllRacesFinished") in the beginning. I need all variables to be state because im using them in the UI
